# Как пользоваться исключениями в Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, исключения

Не могу понять как словить исключения в Qt. Кто-нибудь может показать пример?
Почему так не работает?

```
void test()
{
    QVector<int> foo;
    foo.at(5); // index out of range
}

int main()
{
    try{
        test();
    }
    catch(...){
        // обрабатываем исключение
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Что значит "не работает"? Поясните, почему вы считаете, что у вас все не в порядке?

Comment: Я привел пример, попробуйте запустить.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Как показал поиск в Интернете, Qt не использует исключения, он просто использует для проверки доступа за пределами диапазона assert.

Вам нужно либо использовать `std::vector`, либо реализовать свою собственную обертку вокруг `QVector`, которая будет генерировать соответствующие исключения.